# can't send diffrent urls when page refresh

Tags: javascript, url, checkbox

I read a lot of threads here, but I found no solution and I tried a lot of suggestions. So I hope to get help this way.
I like to read a checkbox state and send when checked a url with parameter checkbx=1 with pagerefresh and when not checked the parameter checkbx=0. When I execute I can not uncheck the checkbox. It resets immediatly back to checked. But the URL in the address-line says ...checkbx=0!?!

Thanks in advance,
Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="test" id="check"><label for="check">Item</label>

 <script>


$(function () {

$('#check').prop("checked", !!localStorage.getItem("darkMode"));

$('#check').on("click", function() {
  var url;
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'true');
    $('img').attr('src', '/full_logo_transparent.png');
    $('link#hueman-main-style-css').attr('href', '/darkstyle.min.css');
    console.log('Dark Mode enabled');
    url = 'index1.php?checkbx=1';
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'false');
    $('link#hueman-main-style-css').attr('href', '/main.min.css');
    console.log("No Dark Mode");
    url = 'index1.php?checkbx=0';
  }
  window.location.href = url;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you’re wanting to accomplish? Most integrations which reference the query section of the URL use location.search. I don’t see anywhere in your code where you’ve referenced the URL to set the value of any element.

Comment: My aim is to send a URL with a parameter to the server with the page refresh, then I like to read the parameter with $_GET['checkbx'] and take the value for building a sql query. Do you unterstand?

Comment: Is there any reason you have to send the checkbox value using a page refresh? You’ve already got AJAX loaded into your page, so you could send a POST request to your server to make it easier. Otherwise, you’ll need to add some logic into your page’s script to check for the URL parameter and then set the checkbox element’s value to checked/unchecked.

Comment: Ok, I will read about POST request with AJAX and try this way. I give feedback tomorrow. Thanks stephancasas so far.

Comment: Where's the code where you're reading 0 or 1? query params are strings, and 0 !== '0',

Comment: No problem! Good luck, and let me know how it works!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the help of a friend, without JS.

```
$che = '';
if($_SESSION['proc_all'] == 1) $che = ' checked';

?>
<input type="checkbox"<?php echo $che; ?> onclick="window.parent.location='<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']."?aktion=1&amp;todo=uebersicht&amp;proc_all=chenge"; ?>'" class="diasel"><label for="check"> Checkbox</label>
```

Thanks anyway!